# Inserting html on the fly and tabs

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm building an add-on that uses a browser overlay.xul, which has included js files.  The easiest way I found to modify HTML on a webpage was this bit of code I found on the mdn I believe.

```
const STATE_START = Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_START;
const STATE_STOP = Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP;

var myListener = {
    QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
        if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener) ||
        aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsWeakReference) ||
        aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports))
        return this;
        throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    },
    onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aFlag, aStatus) { },
    onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI) {
        PageLoad.initialzed = false;
        PageLoad.init();
    },
    onProgressChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, curSelf, maxSelf, curTot, maxTot) { },
    onStatusChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStatus, aMessage) { },
    onSecurityChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aState) { }
};

gBrowser.addProgressListener(myListener);


var PageLoad = {
    initialzed : false,
    browser : null,
    domain : null,
    appcontent : null,

    init : function() {
        PageLoad.appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
        if (PageLoad.appcontent) {
            PageLoad.appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", PageLoad.load, true);
        }
    },
    load : function() {
                //I do this so it only calls the function once
        if (PageLoad.initialzed == false) {
            PageLoad.initialzed = true;
            PageLoad.browser = gBrowser.contentDocument;
            PageLoad.domain  = (PageLoad.browser.location.host.match(/([^.]+)\.\w{2,3}(?:\.\w{2})?$/) || [])[1];
            myFunctiontoInsertHTML();
        }

    }
};
```

Then I can use `PageLoad.browser.createElement('div')` and so on in my function.. This works good so far but I have come across a problem that with multiple tabs open, my `PageLoad.domain` variable contains the domain of the last loaded tab or web page (which in turn causes errors inserting html on 2 or more different pages/tabs). So what I want to change is everytime the user clicks on a different tab or reloads the page I want to call the function but I have run into a dead end.

Comment: check out [on page load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load) and [url bar listner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners#Example:_Notification_when_the_value_in_Address_Bar_changes)

Comment: I was using my own variation of that 'on page load' link but this url bar listener is exactly what I need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

`gBrowser.contentDocument` is the document of the page loaded in the current browser tab - as soon as the user switches tabs or navigates to a different page its value changes and you shouldn't keep the old value (it is a memory leak). You are observing the progress of all browser tabs, you should look at the one that you got called for. Meaning in your case: `aProgress.DOMWindow` (see [nsIWebProgress.DOMWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWebProgress#Attributes)). That's also where you should attach your `DOMContentLoaded` event listener if you are interested in the load progress of a single tab.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir for all your help so far. I seem to have run into a larger issue with `gBrowser.addProgressListener`.

Oddly enough, after I install the addon, it works. If I close my browser and  start it back up again, the addon works again, as expected however if I close the browser again and open it back up it doesn't work.

Looking in the error console it says that "`gBrowser.addProgressListener` is not a function". The addon will not work again until I re-install it. Rinse and repeat, if you restart the browser 3 times it doesn't work anymore.